# Can't disable semantic wisent-python-default-setup on python-mode-hook

Tags: python, semantic-mode

Here is the error when semantic by default add `wisent-python-default-setup` into hook `python-mode-hook`.
It's shown in minibuffer.

> Makeing python-shell-interpreter-args local to *Python Internal[ org-src-fontification:python-mode]* while let-bound!

It happens when I open Org-buffer with Babel Python code block, and python source code file.

I found relative issue here:

- https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/531

Then I try to remove this from hook by the following code:

```lisp
(remove-hook 'python-mode-hook 'wisent-python-default-setup)
```

But this does not work, after Emacs finished start, I check out `python-mode-hook`, it's still over there.

I guess maybe semantic is enabled after my upper "removing it from hook". But I don't know when and where. (Maybe someone can tell me how to debug it)

Comment: That's just a warning. Might result in a bug sometimes, but must not. Probably you may ignore this.

Comment: I don't know what caused Emacs suspend, but when this message appears, then Emacs suspend, so I want to disable it, maybe I need to disable the whole semantic?

Comment: And consider a bug-report?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, could be semantic enabled after my remove hook, so it is added again. I don't know where, and how to find it out.