# What does "Making browse-url-browser-function local to *eww* while let-bound!" mean?

Tags: advice, eww, slime

I am using SLIME (which includes hyperspec.el). I wanted to view the HyperSpec using Emacs' EWW instead of the desktop web browser (e.g. Firefox, Chromium, etc.). To do this, I added an advice to set the web browser to EWW for looking at the HyperSpec:

```
(advice-add 'hyperspec-lookup
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```

However, I always get the following message in the `*Messages*` buffer the first time I use `hyperspec-lookup` after starting Emacs.

```
Making browse-url-browser-function local to *eww* while let-bound!
```

Is this an error message? What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't know what `hyperspec-lookup` is or does. But the message means that you've made variable `browse-url-browser-function` a buffer-local variable, but it is a local variable bound by `let`.  Your code (above) let-binds that variable, and within the `let` some code makes it a buffer-local variable. You can use `debug-on-entry` for `hyperspec-lookup` to walk through the debugger and see what code makes it a buffer-local variable.

Comment: A guess is that you want to use `setq-local` there, to set the value of `browse-url-browser-function`, instead of let-binding it.

Comment: However, see [this `emacs-devel@gnu.org message](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2013-11/msg00620.html) from @stefan in 2013. He seems to suggest ignoring that message and that he maybe shouldn't have added it. Dunno whether his comment in that message applies generally or just to that case. On the other hand, [this 2010 message](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-12/msg00528.html) from him suggests that the message usually indicates a problem. Maybe he will chime in here, to clarify things.

Comment: Here's [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/15226/105) on emacs.SE that's about the same error message.

Comment: @Drew Replacing the let-binding with `setq-local` solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Feel free to add an answer saying that. Any answer will likely be more helpful than no comments. (Comments can be deleted at any time.) Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by replacing the let-binding with `setq-local`:

```
(advice-add 'hyperspec-lookup
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (setq-local browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url)
              (apply orig-fun args)))
```